# Change URL received by PHP (throug .htaccess?)

Tags: php, url

I am learning PHP by building a project from laracasts.com. I am running a XAMPP stack.

In the project I am reading the URL that the browser sends me by reading $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].
When I type in the browser

> http://localhost/php-learning/

I receive

> /php-learning/

which is what I expect. But when I type in the browser

> http://localhost/php-learning/contact

I get an error 404: Object not found. Only when I type

> http://localhost/php-learning/index.php/contact

I recieve

> /php-learning/index.php/contact

Can someone suggest me a place where I can learn what is happening here? And how can I get rid of the index.php in my url?

Maybe for many of you this is a very basic question, but I am learning ;-))

Kind regards,

Hubert

With respect to adapting vhosts:

```
I can only find a file httpd-vhosts.conf which contains
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify your Nginx/Apache vhosts config , There you would find a rule which would state to include "index.php"  for / path. Just add a slash before  index.php then it would look like /index.php.
The problem is when you don't add / before index.php, it would try to find a separate index.php in your sub-directory paths. So if you add / before it, then it would always use the root index.php file.